# is the throws usernamenotfound exception mandatory in spring loaduserbyusername

Tags: spring, exception, spring-security

Is it mandatory to define the loaduserbyusername  method with throws usernamenotfound exception in spring security ???

```
         public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException
```

Well i get a findbugs error saying redundant throws of usernamenotfoundexception .. how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just that you do not have to declare the `throws UsernameNotFoundException` in your method signature, because `UsernameNotFoundException` is a runtime exception.

See [this](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#RedundantThrows) for a detailed explanation.